# How did Joey & Chandler's Chick and Duck die?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

I don't remember what happened to the first Chick and Duck that Joey and 
Chandler kept. Did they show in the show how they died? If yes, then please tell me the episode.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They died, probably of old age, but it wasn't shown in the show. It has been revealed in the final episode, when Joey bought the *Chick Jr.* and *Duck Jr.* The group had lied to Joey that they had gone to a special farm where they were very happy but could not be visited.

From [the script](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/1017.shtml):

> Joey: It's my house-warming present for Monica and Chandler.
>
> Phoebe: It's a baby chick and duck!
>
> Joey: Uh-huh. And I named them Chick Jr. and Duck Jr.
>
> Phoebe: I did not see that coming.
>
> Joey: Yeah, I figure they'll love it at the new house, you know? It
>   has that big backyard. ***And then, when they get old***, they can go to
>   that special farm that Chandler took the other chick and duck to.
>
> Phoebe: Yes.
>
> Joey: Yeah. It's a shame people can't visit there.
>
> Phoebe: That is the rule, though.

Comment: I think you might have missed the joke here. They didn't go to a farm :-) also, ducks can live for 20+ years

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the old age explanation in multiple places before, not only the [Friends Wikia](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Chick_and_The_Duck#Abrupt_disappearance), but I wasn't aware of the ducks lifespan :-) I've modified my answer a bit.

Comment: I see no good reason to assume they died of advanced age.

Answer (score 12):

It seems likely that Chandler had them humanely destroyed. In the final episode there's a mention that they were taken to a **special farm that can't be visited** in order to live out the remainder of their lives.

> **Joey:** *Yeah, I figure they'll love it at the new house, you know? It has that big backyard. And then, **when they get old, they can go to
>   that special farm that Chandler took the other chick and duck to.***

The average lifespan of a duck is [8-12 years](https://www.beautyofbirds.com/domesticatedducks.html) and anything upwards of 20 years depending on the breed. The average lifespan of a well kept rooster can be anything between around 12-15 years so it seems highly unlikely either would be approaching old-age, even ***ignoring the possibility that they both coincidentally happened to die at the same time***.

---

This whole gag is very strongly reminiscent of the 'Milner's Farm' joke from [Season 1, episode 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583653/) where Ross learns the fate of his beloved pet dog Chi-Chi.

Comment: I don't think Chandler would had them destroyed as he loved them very much.

Comment: I think @chanandler Bong is right. They may have died of old age.

Comment: @theflash - You're welcome to keep telling yourself that

Comment: @Richard: for all we know, they ended up as some more delicious “vegetarian” pâté for Phoebe.

Comment: @pauld.waite - I'm intrigued/amused at all the people voting for the "wishful thinking" answer.

Comment: I signed up for `movies` just to upvote this. They did not get old. Sending beloved pets "to a farm" (when the actually died) is one of the oldest tropes about pets I know!

Comment: @Dan But does it always mean that they have been killed? I don't think so. That's why I don't understand why my answer has been called wishful thinking by Richard. It would be wishful thinking if I wrote that they were really in a farm.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong - There's the possibility that they both simultaneously died for no apparent reason. But that seems unlikely.

Comment: @Richard I always thought that one of them died, they told Joey that it has been sent to the farm and then, sometime later, the other died and Joey was told the same.

Comment: @chanandlerbong - That may well be, but then we're back to guesswork.

Answer (score 11):

The chick and the duck died of unknown reasons, likely age or eating something they shouldn't have. Joey was told they went [to live on a farm](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReleasedToElsewhere) because Joey is a giant [man-child](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ManChild) and can't be expected to handle the truth.

Rachel confirms they die in the last episode, without any ***stupid*** mention of being put down or euthanasia.

> Joey: Sure, yeah. Will you just keep an eye on the chick [jr] and the duck [jr]?
>
> Rachel: Chick and the duck? ***Didn't they die...***
>
> Phoebe: (interrupting) Dive. Yeah, they dove head-first into fun on the farm.

**Chandler specifically kept the chick, and the duck, because he's against euthanasia**. Instead of letting the chick be put down, he kept it, and ended up saving the duck, which was already mature/adult (not a duckling). He would never have them put down short of terminal illness or crippling age. He also wouldn't let Monica kill them, not that Monica would ever do that either. **Neither of their characters are that heartless.**

From Season 3 Episode 21, where the chick and the duck first appeared:

> Chandler: If they can’t find a home for her, they kill her! And I’m not gonna let that happen to little Yasmine [the chick]!

The Duck is some age older than the Chick, as it was fully grown by the time Chandler saved it. This can explain how they could have died near the same time.

---

They were last seen in Season 6, and the last time they were mentioned ***but not seen on screen*** before the final was Season 7 Episode 2 "The One With Rachel’s Book":

Comment: This answer has more proof of Chandler's views on the subject than others here. While it's still not proof of what actually happened, nor if both died at the same time, it is great for speculating that whatever did happen was likely humane. Also, Rachel asking, "Didn't they die," is more generic than, "Didn't they get killed." The fact is, we don't know the circumstances, but it is unlikely we should paint a picture of Chandler as knife wielding, bird slayer just to make room in the apartment or because Monica wouldn't have them. Maybe he found a new home for them with someone else.

Comment: I agree with you. Since it wasn't shown in the show all we can do is make speculations on what may have happened and the point you made about Rachel asking "Didn't they die" makes it more clear that they may have died of some factors other than Chandler killing them...+1 for that @ventaur

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because they ate Rachel's face cream. It was in the episode The One with Rachel's Book. That was the last time they were mentioned and they were throwing up everywhere that is why Joey ended up sleeping in Rachel's bedroom. So I don't think Chandler killed them, it's just that maybe they were poisoned by the face cream they ate.

Comment: Only the duck ate it, though.

Answer (score -1):

When they all went to England Phoebe did not feed Chick and Duck for four days probably that's the time they died. I didn't see them after that in any of the episodes.

Comment: No, that was in season 5, and they did appear after that. For instance, the duck ate Rachel's face cream when she lived with Joey, and that was in season 7. [Here's a list detailing of their appearances on the show.](http://friendstvshow.net/show/the-chick-and-the-duck/)